# How to protect users' credentials stored unencrypted in ~/.docker/config.json by 'docker login'?

Tags: docker, gnupg, password-storage

I have a Docker registry deployed on a server, where multiple persons can login as *root*. This local registry is used to pull and push Docker images in a remote registry hosted in an Artifactory instance. However, whenever a person makes a *docker login* to an Artifactory repository with its credentials, Docker stores his/her credentials unencrypted in a base64 encoding in *~/.docker/config.json*. Since the host of the local Docker registry is accessible from multiple persons, it puts his/her credentials at risk from others.

I searched and found alternatives to resolve this problem. According to *[docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/)* documentation, the Docker Engine can keep user credentials in an external credentials store using an external helper program. From the list of currently available credentials helpers, I chose *pass* one. I followed the instructions followed by other users [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/102), and I successfully created a directory  under *~/*, where every credential could be stored encrypted:

```
[root@hostname ~]# ls -a .password-store/
.  ..  .gpg-id
[root@hostname ~]# pass
Password Store
```

It didn't take me long to realise that this didn't actually solve my problem. Let me explain. By running *docker login* for the first time after the above setup, the following directories were created:

```
[root@hostname ~]# docker login repository-name.artifactory-url
Username: myUserName
Password:
[root@hostname ~]# pass
Password Store
└── docker-credential-helpers
    └── cmVwb3NpdG9yeS1uYW1lLmFydGlmYWN0b3J5LXVybA==
        └── myUserName
```

The password is now encrypted in *myUserName.gpg* file under *~/.password-store/docker-credential-helpers/cmVwb3NpdG9yeS1uYW1lLmFydGlmYWN0b3J5LXVybA==/* directory, using the private key which corresponds to gpg-id included in *~/.password-store/.gpg-id* file.

If a second person executes *docker login* as above, his/her credentials will be encrypted with the same private key as before. And then of course decrypted with the same public key. This is because docker automatically saves every new password under the same directory, *~/.password-store/docker-credential-helpers/*, using always *~/.password-store/.gpg-id* file. If every person had his/her credentials stored under a different path, then an alternative *.gpg-id* file would be used for him/her, and thus a different private-public key pair.

Has anyone an idea how to overcome either the problem with the unencrypted credentials in ~/.docker/config.json, or the problem with *pass* utility I described?

My OS is a CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009.